# Spring Mongodb: Subtract two dates

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm running against an issue related to spring data MongoDB.

I need to subtract two dates: `now - fieldDate`.

Nevertheless, it's come me up this problem with spring data MongoDB: I'm not able to subtract dates! I mean:

[image]

As you can see, I'm only able to add a `Number`, a `field reference` or any `AggregationExpression`.

I'd like to build this kind of expression:

```
ArithmeticOperators.Subtract.valueOf(Date.from(Instant.now())).subtract("fieldname");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

you should use Subtract function inside project pipeline. You can not directly call Subtract function outside the pipeline. So your query should be :

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation=Aggregation.project().and(Subtract.valueOf(Date.from(Instant.now())).subtract("fieldname"));
```